# Xcode 6 doesnt build to device but says its running

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I installed xcode 6 and was working on my app on simulator. 
Now i have added push support it was time to start working on the device.

The problem is i cant get it to work. The device sits there and does nothing. Xcode says the app is running on the device but nothing happens.

When i click on "Running app on device" i can see its in the status of

"Validating Application "

The whole time...

I tried the solutions on SO but they are all for xcode 4 and some points about architechture and info.plist. 
Checked both nothing wrong with it (testing on 5s, 7.1). 
Tested other apps (got from github and so on), same problem cant run on device.

I think it has to do with xcode because all projects (big and small,old and new) don't work. I also tried on my ipad same problem.

So its not related to project or device.

Anyone has a solution ?

Comment: Close your Xcode and also Delete all the Derived Data and then open Xcode again and try.

Comment: restart your xcode and simulator

Comment: Restarted phone,laptop,xcode doesnt work (this problem is since yesterday). Removed Derived data and exited and started again doesnt help. Same problem. I think it has to do with xcode. because all projects dont work and tried on my ipad same problem. So project and device is out of the question...

Comment: You have a big file? For example with more, more, more lines of code? Have you try to clean build folder (cmd+alt+shift+k)?

Comment: @weso no it has nothing to do with the project.. It's also small btw

Comment: Have you tried delete the profile provisioning from the device?

Comment: I also saw a lot of odd behavior when i first installed XCode 6.  Did find my initial download was corrupt and would not reinstall so downloaded a fresh copy which installed successfully and ran properly.

Answer (score 0):

Removed xcode and installed it again. Works.
But to be honest since Xcode 4 this is the worst Xcode, allot of hangs and crashes. Need to force quit at least 6 times a day.